# Почему закрываются скрины из gnu screen после запуска?

Tags: bash, gnu-screen

У меня есть bash скрипт который читает из файла директории, и по очереди запускает файл start.sh в каждой из директорий в новом скрине. Но через время (менее секунды) скрины закрываются, но некоторые остаются. Каждый файл start.sh запускается по отдельности нормально.

Скрипт для запуска всех файлов:

```bash
killall screen

start_files="start_files.txt"

while IFS= read -r start_dir
do
    IFS='/' read -ra array <<< "$start_dir"
    screen_name=${array[-1]}
    echo "Running: $start_dir | $screen_name"

    screen -S $screen_name -d -m sh "$start_dir/start.sh"
done < <(grep "" $start_files)
```

Код start.sh (во всех директориях файл одинаковый, ток пути отличаются):

```bash
. /home/brainfuck/fourex/brainfuck-on-top-utilities-bot/venv/bin/activate
python3.10 /home/brainfuck/fourex/brainfuck-on-top-utilities-bot/main.py
```

И вот так хранится список директорий (start_files.txt):

```
/home/brainfuck/fourex/brainfuck-on-top-utilities-bot
/home/brainfuck/fourex/ts
/home/brainfuck/fourex/MidTak
/home/brainfuck/Lime/LimeOn
/home/brainfuck/Lime/Pil
/home/brainfuck/mlevigen/randombot
```

Этот скрипт который запускает все файлы, предназначен для запуска/перезапуска всех ботов и тд. на сервере.

Ну и вот сама проблема:
[image]

Comment: Вероятнее всего start.sh заканчивает свое выполнение ошибкой и screen закрывается, добавьте в него лоигрование и посмотрите что происходит в скрипте на момент остановки

Comment: Когда я запускаю по одиночке start.sh, то ошибок нету

Comment: в любом случае попробуйте все же перенаправить вывод, вначале скрипта `set -x; exec 2>/tmp/debug_scriprt.tmp`, после падения скрипта посмотрите что в конце лога будет, может быть ему окружений не хватает или в оболочке screen что-то меняется

Comment: Side note: попробуйте улучшить цикл запуска, например как сделано вот здесь: https://github.com/andy-shev/buildroot/blob/intel/board/intel/common/post-image.sh.